# What's the best way of knowing which wordpress event to hook into?

Tags: wordpress, action, hook

Say, you wanted to carry out some action when you click on the publish post button when creating a new post. For the sake of an example, let's say you wanted an email to be automatically sent to somebody  everytime you create a post.

The question is what's the best way to know which core functions are available to hook into - to carry out the emailing.

Or is it that, you kind of guess it - relying strictly on your WordPress API memory? For example, you could think that since this action has to do with creating a post, you should search for function names in the plugin/actions codex page containing the word `post` in them and then scan them thru to perhaps pick up items such as wp_insert_post, wp_update_post, save_post, post_X, X_post etc etc? Is this the norm?

For this particular case, you will probably ending up with either wp_insert_post or save_post. But my question is general. Is this the right way to approach to the problem?

Or.. is there another or more efficient way ( perhaps a plug in )  to let me know which ( hookable) core functions have run in the current or in the previous request? This way, I could get a definitive list of all the related functions for me to choose from or read about **which are directly dealing with the current request that I'm interested in**. No more guess work...

note that because of the header redirects, current request may not cut it, you would need to be able to get a list of all hookable functions in the previous request. ( the one that just has run before the redirect code was encountered ).

Comment: The Stack Exchange network has [an entire site dedicated to WordPress](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/), so this question would be a much better fit over there, rather than Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I figure out what hooks are available is simple; I install a copy of WordPress using a local Apache/MySQL and then I use the [PhpStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) + [Zend Debugger](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/configuring-zend-debugger.html) and trace through the code and see what hooks fire. From there I just decide which hook is best based on the context of my needs, usually if there are several hooks that are potential it's pretty obvious which one to use.

There are other approaches such as [instrumenting the list of hooks](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/307/where-can-i-find-a-list-of-wordpress-hooks/339#339) and there are probably ways to get that information using (add-ons to) the Debug Bar, but in my experience all of those approaches are like fumbling around in the dark looking for a light switch. And if you use a debugger it's like turning on the light switch where you get to see exactly where the light switch is with no wasted effort.